# How can I use one POST route to accept an array or object in different methods?

Tags: python, flask

My ideal would be to have two functions annotated with:

`@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])`

I want one to accept a single json object and the other to accept an array of json objects like this:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def handle_single_object():
    data = request.json()
    print(data)
    return(data)
```

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def handle_array_object():
    data = request.json()
    for i in data:
        print(i)
    return(data)
```

Essentially, I want the router to route based on the structure of the JSON. This is possible in other frameworks like Rocket for Rust. Is this possible with flask or do I have to define different routes?

Comment: @rdas `Accept` specifies the expected response type, not the content type. And the content will be `application/json` in both cases -- there isn't a different type for a single object versus array.

Comment: You've got it backwards. The client sends the `Accept:` header to tell the server what MIME type it can accept in response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unify the processing of the received data. Do the processing of both the array and the object. For example through IF. **But it's better to use one interface to access the API.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).